# Is it possible to bind to events on a child window from a parent?

Tags: javascript, dom, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to bind functions to events on child windows?

```
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() {
    var newWindow= window.open('other.html', "_blank");
    newWindow.document.addEventListener("onreadystatechange", function(){
      console.log('foo'); // This is never run. Can I construct the new window so that it is run "onreadystatechange"?
    });

    return false;   
};
```

Note that I would like to bind an event to `onreadystatechange`. I wish to avoid a race condition, can I create a window, bind the events and then load the URL to avoid the race condition?

Comment: you should not use event handler properties like `.onclick = ...`, use the `.addEventListener()` apis instead

Comment: "Is it possible", have you tried it? If you encountered problems it would be worth mentioning them in the question

Comment: I have tried running the code in the question and the event function does not appear to be run. I suspect because it is losing the race with the `onreadystatechange` event firing. I have not tried avoiding the race condition because I know of no way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.addEventListener("onreadystatechange", ...)`

Event properties start with "on". The event *names* on the other hand do not. I.e. it should be

`.addEventListener("readystatechange", ...)`

> I have not tried avoiding the race condition because I know of no way to do so.

Ok, I'm not entirely sure how events and auxiliary browsing context initialization work with window.open(), the spec is quite complex there.
I'd just try setting DOM event breakpoints (chrome debugger has those) and see which events are fired in which order and then check if that works in other browsers.

That said, I think the simplest option here might to read the `document.readyState` property. If it's "complete" then the site is already fully loaded and no further state change event will be fired and you can execute your script directly instead of waiting for the event.

Comment: I want to supply the script to run from the parent window. Can you think how I could do so?

Comment: either inject a `<script>` tag or try `targetWindow.eval()`

Answer (score 2):

If you do this should be good to go.

```
var newwindow = window.open('other.html', "_blank");
var $ = newwindow.$; // add if needed
$(newwindow).bind('someEvent', function() { FunctionThatDoesSomethingInTheNewWindow });
return false;
```

Comment: It looks like your answer is assuming the presence of jquery, which isn't mentioned in the question

Comment: How is this different to the code in the question (apart from using JQuery)?